# Prevent Laravel session overlap on subdomains

Tags: laravel, session, subdomain, session-cookies

I have two ***independent*** copies of a same Laravel app on my domain, each one behaves as expected when used exclusively:

```
app1.mydomain.com
app2.mydomain.com
```

They do have different `APP_NAME` values in their respective `.env` files. I do want the two to be completely independent (thus all of the rational env variables are set appropriately unique, e.g: the `APP_KEY`s, `APP_NAME`s, `APP_URL`s, etc). While two distinct databases are designated (though on a same host, of course), I've put an identical "user" on both of the databases.

The thing is, sometimes when they're being utilized together (kinda concurrently), a `419` error shows up when I'm already logged into one of them through the "user" credentials, and try to log into the other one through a distinct but identical "user" credentials! Seems like the `app2` thinks the user is already logged in; while the user is already logged into the other supposedly independent subdomain. I've tried `SESSION_COOKIE` and `SESSION_DOMAIN` environment variables to no avail.

By setting the `SESSION_DOMAIN`s to `app1.mydomain.com` and `app2.mydomain.com` respectively; you may log into one of them successfully; but trying to log into the other one displays the error page of 419! Also, the domain entries for the session in the browser are set with a preceding dot, e.g: `.app1.mydomain.com` (while when you omit the `SESSION_DOMAIN`s, the values do appear without the leading dot.)

I've noticed a session of `app1_session` does also show up in the browser cookies for `app2.mydomain.com` (and sometimes a session of `laravel_session` do also show up! the [`laravel`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/session.php#L131) is a default string substituted whenever the environment variable of `APP_NAME` is not read by the system!)

So, what's wrong and how can I fix it?!

Comment: Do they have different values for `APP_KEY`?

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: @Donkarnash Sure, they do also have different values for `APP_KEY`.

Comment: @Pelmered The session driver is `file`.

Comment: And they use different storage folders? I think you just need to make the session cookie name unique for each of the apps. Make it based on the URL maybe?

Comment: @Pelmered Sure, they definitely use different storage folders; the "session cookie names" are also already unique! (they're generated based on the `APP_NAME`, which are unique in turn.)

Comment: @goodUser plz make sure your `APP_URL` also must be unique for both `subdomains`

Comment: @khawarAli They do have unique `APP_URL`s, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting up each `.env` file pointing to each separate sub domain. The functionality you may be after is setting the `same_site` value to `strict`.

This will ensure only cookies that are from the defined domain are accepted.

P.S. for good measure, a `php artisan config:clear` once you change it.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I've tried the `strict` value for the `same_site` attribute in the `config/session.php` file to no avail! (having the configs cleared through the artisan command)

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a Problem on Any of your subdomains Probably . I think You where checking out Both the site on same browser instance that why this issue is occuring try to use one on normal browser mode & open another on Private mode (or) Incognito mode ... it would probably works on your case ....

If it does not works for you Implement A Laravel Session Table So you can Track Session IDs of logged in user having a current session i hope it works for you

Comment: I do utilize them on a single browser instance in different tabs, and through a same user credentials; I've tried your suggestion (to invoke one on a normal browser and the other in private mode), to no avail; the issue still persists!

Comment: I think you where using a same database connection ..checkout out your database name if its not the issue ...checkout the session ID on session table

Comment: Thanks for the reply; Actually, I don't use the "database" driver for the sessions at all, I use the "file" driver; other than that, I'm totally certain I use different database connections for each app. However, how the "session ID tracking", as you suggest, would help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happening to me, fixed by setting different values for `SESSION_COOKIE=` inside each project .env